# Chocolate Distribution Problem among the student so the difference between maximum Chocolate and minimum Chocolate will be minimum

Tags: python

The difference between the number of chocolates in the packet with maximum chocolates and the packet with minimum chocolates given to the students is minimum.

```
lst = [7,3,2,4,9,12,56]
student = 3
minimum difference = 2
```

Tried to find the combinations from a list and get the minimum and maximum value from the list and get the difference

Comment: Do you have a question or just felt like sharing?

Answer (score -2):

```
from itertools import combinations
def choco(lst, std):
    list_comb = list(combinations(lst, std))
    minimum_diff = 99999
    for i in list_comb:
        diff = max(i) - min(i)
        if diff < minimum_diff:
            minimum_diff = diff
    return minimum_diff
lst = [7,3,2,4,9,12,56]
student = 3
print (choco(lst, student))
```